# How do I save the FOV in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In C:\Users\Username\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Skyrim.ini I have this line under [General]

```
fdefaultfov=90
```

When I enter the game, I bring up the console to ensure it really is FOV 90. I type in **fov 90** but my FOV changes, which means the ini file is not doing anything.

If I close the game, obviously it won't save the console command.

What am I doing wrong, or where can I set the FOV permanently?

Comment: mine stopped working as well, I wonder if it has anything to do with the recent patch, they may have renamed the field to something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods I've read that should permanently set the FOV in Skyrim.

From http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/mipyc/protip_for_screenshots_in_skyrim_type_tm_into_the/c31anyt :

> FOV=90 resets every time you restart the game. **setcameraFOV 90**
>   should write the setting permanently into your .ini.

From http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2227329 :

> 1. Go to C:\Users[USERNAME]\Documents\My Games\Skyrim
> 2. Open SkyrimPrefs.ini, and search for [General] section
> 3. Add fdefaultfov=XX at the end of the section. (where XX is the FOV value you want to change to). For example add fdefaultfov=90
> 4. Open Skyrim.ini, and search for [Display] section
> 5. Add fDefaultWorldFOV=XX (where XX is the FOV value you put in
>          fdefaultfov)
> 6. Add fDefault1stPersonFOV=xx.0000 (where XX is the FOV value you put
>          in fdefaultfov)

I've only used the second method listed above. You might want to try the first method first as it is simpler to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use these two lines

```
fDefaultWorldFOV=80
fDefault1stPersonFOV=80.0000
```

in Skyrim.ini under [Display]